# how to reload the template when working with enlive without restar

Tags: clojure, ring, enlive

I am using enlive for my web development. I start my ring server in repl using `(serve my-app/handler)`

However when I make changes to any of my html templates I have to restart my repl for the changes to show up. How do I reload my markup without restarting the repl ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reevaluate lines that read the template. For example in my project I would have to reevaluate ("C-x C-e" in Emacs) the following line:

```
(def table-template (h/html-resource "META-INF/web/table.html"))
```

If you don't use Emacs you could try require namespace that contains templates with :reload, please see this: [force clojure :reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902545/force-clojure-reload)

Comment: thanks for replying. However how do I also reload it if I am using a deftemplate - `(deftemplate chrome "mfaiz/templates/chrome.html" [page]
  [:#main] (content "Hello World")))`

Comment: You should be able to do the same: either reevaluated this expression or entire namespace where template is defined. If you take a look at definition of [deftemplate](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/blob/master/src/net/cgrand/enlive_html.clj#L583) it calls [template](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/blob/master/src/net/cgrand/enlive_html.clj#L573) which in its order calls [html-resource](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/blob/master/src/net/cgrand/enlive_html.clj#L66).